# PHP:checked attribute in array of checkboxes

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I have an array like this

```
$current_asset = [
    ['name'=>'Land,'id'=>1],
    ['name'=>'Building ,'id'=>2],
    ['name'=>'Machinery','id'=>3],
];

<?php 
 foreach($current_asset as $key=>$value){ ?>
 <input type="checkbox" name="current_asset[]" value="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>">

 <?php } ?>
```

My question how can I add checked attribute in if one of the value is checked when the form populated with the `POST` data

I am getting the checkbox array like this on form submit

Here are the current checkboxes on form submit (ie values of `current_asset`)

```
Array(
    0=>1
    1=>1
   )
```

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: I presume that you want to have the checkbox checked when you print out the `<input >`, but what defines if the value is supposed to be checked?

Comment: Or is it a question of how to know which array element was chosen after submission?  In which case, I would suggest making the array to be an associative array where the index is the id number.

Comment: @Andreas when the form is populated with old data i want to add the checked attributte to the checkbox

Comment: @TimMorton can you give an example??

Comment: So what attribute in the old data signifies that the checkbox should be checked?  I don't see anything that would tell me whether to check the box or not.  Nor do I see anything to compare to (ie, new vs old)

Comment: @TimMorton updated my question

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do some kind of check before printing

```
$html=‘’;
foreach($current_asset as $asset) {
 if($asset[‘hasBeenCheckedBefore’]) {
  $checked = ‘checked’;
 } else {
  $checked = ‘’;
 }
 $html .= “$asset[‘name’] <input type=‘checkbox’ name=‘current_asset[]’ value=‘$asset[“id”]’ $checked />”;
}
```

Comment: Yup, but after your `foreach` and before hte `if` you'll want to set `$checked='';` or similar, so that 1 - no undefined var warning/error, and 2- after the first checked value is found it is reset for the next trip through the loop.

Comment: True! Edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of one way to do it.  I have changed your data structure to be easier to use. I was confused initially because you didn't mention any way to store data.  So this is only good for the one page view.

```
<?php

// initialize data

/**
 * Data structure can make the job easy or hard...
 *
 * This is doable with array_search() and array_column(),
 * but your indexes might get all wonky.
 */
$current_asset = [
    ['name'=>'Land','id'=>1],
    ['name'=>'Building' ,'id'=>2],
    ['name'=>'Machinery','id'=>3],
];

/**
 * Could use the key as the ID.  Note that it is being
 * assigned as a string to make it associative.
 */
$current_asset = [
    '1'=>'Land',
    '2'=>'Building',
    '3'=>'Machinery',
];

/**
 * If you have more information, you could include it
 * as an array.  I am using this setup.
 */
$current_asset = [
    '1'=> ['name' => 'Land',      'checked'=>false],
    '2'=> ['name' => 'Building',  'checked'=>false],
    '3'=> ['name' => 'Machinery', 'checked'=>false],
];


// test for post submission, set checked as appropriate
if(array_key_exists('current_asset', $_POST)) {
  foreach($_POST['current_asset'] as $key => $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($key,$current_asset)) {
      $current_asset[$key]['checked'] = true;
    }
  }
}



// begin HTML output
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- content .... -->

    <form method="post">
    <?php foreach($current_asset as $key=>$value): ?>
      <?php $checked = $value['checked'] ? ' checked' : ''; ?>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="current_asset[<?= $key ?>]" value="<?= $key ?>"<?= $checked ?>>
        <?= htmlentities($value['name']) ?>
      </label>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </form>

  <body>
</html>
```